I want to disable the Formik validation when loading a modal
I am using Formik and Yup in my React Typescript project , I have a modal that will save a new value , I added Formik Validation to the Fields in my modal but when I click the add button in my page to load the modal it validates the fields and shows the error message
const validationSchema = () => {
    return Yup.object().shape({
      role_category: Yup.string().required("This field is required!"),
      description: Yup.string().required("This field is required!"),
    });
  };
  const initialValues = {
    role_category: "",
    description: "",
  };

    return (
        <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
          <ToastContainer limit={2} position="top-center" />
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        //validateOnsubmit={true}
        //validateOnMount={false}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}
      >
        {({ setFieldValue, values }) => (
          <Form>
            <div className="title" style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
              <div className="card-title card-title-set-container">
                <div className="card-title-text">Role Category</div>{" "}
              </div>
              <ConfirmationModalContextProvider>
                <div className="card-grid card-grid-set-container">
                  <div>
                    <Row className="btn-position">
                      <Button
                        size="s"
                        class="primary"
                        name="Add"
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={false}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setId(undefined);
                          setFieldValue("role_category", "");
                          setFieldValue("description", "");

                          toggleModal();
                        }}
                      ></Button>
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <Row style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                      <DataTable
                        rows={roles}
                        columns={[
                          {
                            field: "id",
                            headerName: "RoleID",
                            width: 10,
                          },

                          {
                            field: "role_category",
                            headerName: "Role Category",
                            width: 150,
                          },
                          {
                            field: "description",
                            headerName: "Description",
                            headerClassName: "MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders",
                            width: 800,
                          },
                          {
                            field: "actions",
                            headerName: "Actions",
                            width: 150,
                            renderCell: (params) => {
                              return (
                                <div>
                                  <img
                                    src={editImage}
                                    className="gridImageEdit"
                                    onClick={(e) => {
                                      setFieldValue(
                                        "role_category",
                                        params.row.role_category
                                      );
                                      setFieldValue(
                                        "description",
                                        params.row.description
                                      );

                                      handleGridEditClick(e, params.row);
                                    }}
                                  ></img>

                                  <DeleteIcon
                                    className="gridImageDelete"
                                    onClick={(e) =>
                                      handleGridDeleteClick(e, params.row)
                                    }
                                  ></DeleteIcon>
                                </div>
                              );
                            },
                          },
                        ]}
                        loading={!roles.length}
                      />
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ConfirmationModalContextProvider>
            </div>

            <div></div>

            <Modal
              width="500px"
              height="350px"
              open={showModal}
              onClose={toggleModal}
            >
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="role_category">Role Category</label>
                <Field
                  name="role_category"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  onBlur={setRoleFieldState(values.role_category)}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="role_category"
                  component="div"
                  className="alert yup-error"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <Field
                  name="description"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  onBlur={setDescriptionFieldState(values.description)}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="description"
                  component="div"
                  className="alert yup-error"
                />
              </div>

              <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <div
                  className="button-container"
                  style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
                >
                  <Button
                    size="s"
                    class="primary"
                    name="Save"
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={
                      roleFieldState === "" || descriptionFieldState === ""
                    }
                    onClick={() => {
                      const roleValue = {
                        role: values.role_category,
                        des: values.description,
                      };

                      handleSave(roleValue);

                      toggleModal();
                    }}
                  ></Button>

                  <Button
                    size="s"
                    class="secondary"
                    name="Cancel"
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={false}
                    onClick={toggleModal}
                  ></Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );

I tried using
     validateOnsubmit={flase}
        validateOnMount={false}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}


but it didn't work
I also changed the button type to "button" and then the validation didn't work at all
I want the red error messages to disappear in modal loading 

If you just remove the type='smubmit' from your button ?
The validation won't be triggered and your modal will appear.
         <Button
                    size="s"
                    class="primary"
                    name="Add"
                    type="button"
                    disabled={false}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setId(undefined);
                      setFieldValue("role_category", "");
                      setFieldValue("description", "");

                      toggleModal();
                    }}
                  ></Button>


Hi Patrick and thanks for your answer , the problem in not loading the modal , when modal is loaded the red error messages is appeared on the modal , I wand to disable the formik validation on Modal loading ,  I tried ValidateOnMount but didn't work
